# Deserializing a JSON stream from an API in .Net Core 3.0 leaving all fields null

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-3.0

I've got a simple WPF / .Net Core 3.0 app which executes a GET on a Web API endpoint:

```
private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

private async Task GetClients()
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientGetDto>));
    var streamTask = httpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://mywebapp.com/api/Clients");
    List<ClientGetDto> clientDtos = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<ClientGetDto>;
}
```

ClientGetDto looks like this:

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FranchiseName { get; set; }
    public int? ProLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? LiteLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? ProSalesLicenses { get; set; }
    public int? LiteSalesLicenses { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartOfAgreementDate { get; set; }
    public int? DebitOrderDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DebitOrderStartDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? ContractAmount { get; set; }
    public bool? DebitOrderFormReceived { get; set; }
    public bool? CancellationReceived { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancellationDate { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRegNo { get; set; }
    public string DbUrl { get; set; }
    public string DbName { get; set; }
    public double? CloudStorageQuota { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int? FranchiseId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsTestDb { get; set; }
    public bool? IsGumtreeRegistered { get; set; }
    public int? FusionClientId { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

and the JSON that is returned by the API is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "clientCode": "cx0007",
    "apiUrl": "https://mywebapp/api",
    "companyName": "ACME Company",
    "franchiseName": "ACME Franchise",
    "proLicenses": 1,
    "liteLicenses": 0,
    "proSalesLicenses": 0,
    "liteSalesLicenses": 0,
    "isActive": true,
    "startOfAgreementDate": "2007-08-01T00:00:00",
    "debitOrderDay": 1,
    "debitOrderStartDate": "2012-03-01T00:00:00",
    "contractAmount": 695.00,
    "debitOrderFormReceived": true,
    "cancellationReceived": false,
    "cancellationDate": "2012-10-18T00:00:00",
    "companyRegNo": "",
    "dbUrl": "mydb.co.za",
    "dbName": "db1",
    "cloudStorageQuota": 5.0,
    "comments": null,
    "franchiseId": null,
    "isTestDb": false,
    "isGumtreeRegistered": false,
    "fusionClientId": null,
    "countryCode": "US"
  },
  ...
]
```

My problem is that the code is correctly deserializing the JSON into a List of ClientGetDto objects, but all the fields are null. It's not throwing any exceptions or anything. I've tried decorating my ClientGetDto model with [DataContract] and [DataMember] but it's made no difference (nor would it, since the names of the fields of the model are exactly the same as those in the JSON data)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark each property with [JsonPropertyName("")] because json is case sensitive (I think).

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you so much! I actually used [DataMember(Name = "xxx")] instead but I think it's the same thing. Thanks!!